# jquery slideshow autoplay with next and previous item thumbnail

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i need a jquery slideshow plugin with displaying next and previuos item as a thumbnail.
is there anyone or i have to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

http://www.robertnyman.com/picture-slides/demo-packages/gallery/index.html

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html

http://slideshow.triptracker.net/

http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/

Answer (score 1):

There are tons, I recommend searching and reading up to find the one that suits you the most...

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-javascript-slideshows-carousels-and-sliders

http://www.vivalogo.com/vl-resources/javascript-slideshows-sliders-carousels

Answer (score 1):

we used the below and its nice.

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html

you can see the implementation at

www.art.com

There are lot of examples.